# MATLAB APPLY CUMSUM IN STEPS

Tags: matlab, cumsum

I have data of integers in x = 500 X 612 matrix.  I need a new variable xx in a 500 X 612 matrix but I need to apply cumsum along each row (500) across 12 column steps and applying cumsum like this 51 times --> 500 X (12 X 51) matrix.  Then I need a for loop to produce 51 plots of the 500 rows and 12 columns of the cumsum time series.  thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've tried? Also, please narrow the scope of your question; as it stands you're asking us to write all of the code for you for a few different tasks.

Comment: Give a small numerical example.  Are you saying that you want to segment your matrix into 51 chunks of size 12, and you want to apply `cumsum` to each of these chunks individually?

Comment: Example...x = [1:12; 13:24].   Let's say i need cumsum applied for both rows and at columns 3,6,9,12 for new variable xx = [1 3 6 4 9 15 7 15 24 10 21 33;  13 27 42 16 33 51 19 39 60 22 45 69]..  Then I'm not sure how to use a for loop or similar in making a simple plot of xx for each cumsum column step of 3 columns across each row.  So, i need 4 plots for xx(1,:) and 4 plots of xx(2,:). Summary -  I need cumsum applied across the columns in steps and simple line plots of the cumsum time series across the columns.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @user2100039 - Yup.  That's what I thought.  You want to break up the matrix into multiple columns and apply `cumsum` to each of these chunks.  I'll write an answer.

Comment: @user2100039 - I've written an answer.  Please check the most recent edits as I had to correct a few lines of code.  Good luck!

Comment: Why don't you just do it? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will rephrase what the question is asking to benefit those who are reading.

---

The OP wishes to segment a matrix into chunks by splitting up the matrix into a bunch of columns.  A `cumsum` is applied to each row individually for each column and are then concatenated together to build a final matrix.  As such, given this source matrix:

```
x =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24
```

Supposing that we wish to split up the matrix by columns 3, 6 and 9 and 12, we will have four chunks to work with.  We do a `cumsum` on each of these blocks individually and piece the final result together.  So the result would like the following:

```
xx =

     1     3     6     4     9    15     7    15    24    10    21    33
    13    27    42    16    33    51    19    39    60    22    45    69
```

---

First, you need to determine how many columns you want to break up the matrix into.  In your case, we wish to segment the matrix into 4 chunks: Columns 1 - 3, columns 4 - 6, columns 7 - 9, and columns 10 - 12.   As such, I'm going to [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) this matrix so that each column is an individual row from a chunk in this matrix.  We then apply `cumsum` over this reshaped matrix and we then reshape it back to what you had originally.

Therefore, do this:

```
num_chunks = 4; %// Columns 3, 6, 9, 12
divide_point = size(x,2) / num_chunks; %// Determine how many elements are in a row for a cumsum
x_reshape = reshape(x.', divide_point, []); %// Get reshaped matrix
xy = cumsum(x_reshape); %// cumsum over all columns individually
xx = reshape(xy, size(x,2), size(x,1)).'; %// Reconstruct matrix
```

In the third line of code, `x_reshape = reshape(x.', divide_point, []);` may seem a bit daunting, but it's actually not that bad.  I had to transpose the matrix first because you want to take each row of a chunk and place them into individual columns so we can perform a `cumsum` on each column.  When you reshape something in MATLAB, it collects values **column-wise** and reshapes the input into an output of a specified size.  Therefore, to collect the rows, we need to collect **row-wise** and so we must transpose this matrix.  Next, `divide_point` tells you how many elements we have for a single row in one chunk.  As such, we want to construct a matrix that is of size `divide_point x N` where `divide_point` tells you how many elements we have in a row of a chunk and `N` is the total number of rows over all chunks.  Because I don't want to calculate how many there are (am rather lazy actually....), the `[]` syntax is to automatically infer this number so that we can get a reshaped matrix that respects the total number of elements in the original input.  We then perform `cumsum` on each of these columns, and then we need to `reshape` this back into the original shape of the input.  With this, we use `reshape` again on the `cumsum` result, but in order to get it back into the row-order that you want, we have to determine the transpose as `reshape` takes values in column-major order, then re-transpose that result.

We get:

```
xx =

     1     3     6     4     9    15     7    15    24    10    21    33
    13    27    42    16    33    51    19    39    60    22    45    69
```

In general, the total number of elements to sum over for a row needs to be evenly divisible by the total number of columns that your matrix contains.  For example, given the above, if you were to try to segment this matrix into 5 chunks, you would certainly get an error as the number of rows to `cumsum` over is not symmetric.

As another example, let's say we wanted to break up the matrix into 6 chunks.  Therefore, by setting `num_chunks = 6`, we get:

```
xx =

     1     3     3     7     5    11     7    15     9    19    11    23
    13    27    15    31    17    35    19    39    21    43    23    47
```

You can see that `cumsum` restarts at every second column, as we desired 6 chunks and to get 6 chunks with a matrix of 12 columns, a chunk is created at every second column.

Comment: thanks.  what is the meaning of the closed bracket [ ] in the "get reshaped matrix"?

Comment: The `[]` means to automatically infer what the total number of columns are given the number of rows.  For example, if we had a `1 x 24` vector, doing `reshape(x, 8, [])` would mean that we have 8 rows, and MATLAB would automatically figure out what the number of columns is to respect the reshaping.  In this case, we would get a `8 x 3` matrix.

Comment: @user2100039 - I've added some more explanation on what the code is doing to get your desired result.

Comment: got it.  trying to improve my MATLAB skills all the time but it's going slowly.  thanks again - you might consider teaching this subject matter.

Comment: No problem! It took me a while to learn this as well :) funny story. I used to teach where I went to school and every year I'd have MATLAB seminars. I certainly do miss teaching! I'm here if you have any more questions. Good luck!